# Missing ';' in MimeMessage savechanges method

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jakarta-mail, sendmail

I am working on sending mail through JavaMail API.
Source code

```
        Properties props = new Properties();
        Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
        Message msg = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(Sender));
        String[] toAddresses = null;
        toAddresses = addToRecepients(f_StrtoAdd, msg, toAddresses);
        String[] ccAddresses = null;
        ccAddresses = addCCRecepients(f_StrccAdd, msg, ccAddresses);

        String[] bccAddresses = null;
        bccAddresses = addBccRecepients(f_StrbccAdd, msg,
                bccAddresses);

        Multipart mp = formMsgContents();

        msg.setSentDate(new Date());
        m_log.warning(""+msg.getSentDate());
        msg.setContent(mp);
        msg.saveChanges();
```

I get exception on msg.saveChanges(); - Exception Message Missing ";".

StackTrace-

```
ErrorHandler errorHandler: Exception message : Missing ';'
ErrorHandler errorHandler: Error in class TestServlet
ErrorHandler errorHandler:  
javax.mail.internet.ParameterList.<init>(ParameterList.java:135)
ErrorHandler errorHandler:  
 javax.mail.internet.ContentType.<init>(ContentType.java:72)
ErrorHandler errorHandler:  
 javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.updateHeaders(MimeBodyPart.java:530)
ErrorHandler errorHandler:  
 javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart.updateHeaders(MimeMultipart.java:133)
ErrorHandler errorHandler:  
 javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.updateHeaders(MimeMessage.java:1393)
ErrorHandler errorHandler:  
 javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.saveChanges(MimeMessage.java:1366)
ErrorHandler errorHandler:  
 TestServlet.service(TestServlet.java:200)
ErrorHandler errorHandler:  
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
ErrorHandler errorHandler:  
 org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
ErrorHandler errorHandler:  
 org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
ErrorHandler errorHandler:  
 org.owasp.csrfguard.CsrfGuardFilter.doFilter(CsrfGuardFilter.java:59)
ErrorHandler errorHandler:  
 org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
ErrorHandler errorHandler:  
 ErrorHandlerFilter.doFilter(ErrorHandlerFilter.java:26)
ErrorHandler errorHandler:  
 org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
ErrorHandler errorHandler:  
 ClickjackFilter.doFilter(ClickjackFilter.java:26)
ErrorHandler errorHandler:  
 org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
ErrorHandler errorHandler:  
 XSSFilter.doFilter(XSSFilter.java:55)
ErrorHandler errorHandler:  
 org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
ErrorHandler errorHandler:  
 com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:125)
ErrorHandler errorHandler:  
 org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
ErrorHandler errorHandler:  
 com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:35)
ErrorHandler errorHandler:  
 org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
ErrorHandler errorHandler:  
 com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter(JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:60)
ErrorHandler errorHandler:  
 org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
ErrorHandler errorHandler:  
 com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
ErrorHandler errorHandler:  
 org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
ErrorHandler errorHandler:  
 org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
ErrorHandler errorHandler:  
 org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
ErrorHandler errorHandler:  
 org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
ErrorHandler errorHandler:  
 org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
ErrorHandler errorHandler:  
 org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
ErrorHandler errorHandler:  
 com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:254)
ErrorHandler errorHandler:  
 org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
ErrorHandler errorHandler:  
 org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
ErrorHandler errorHandler:  
 org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
ErrorHandler errorHandler:  
 org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
ErrorHandler errorHandler:  
 com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
ErrorHandler errorHandler:  
 org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
ErrorHandler errorHandler:  
 com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:146)
ErrorHandler errorHandler:  
 com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:480)
ErrorHandler errorHandler:  
 com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:438)
ErrorHandler errorHandler:  
 com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:445)
ErrorHandler errorHandler:  
 com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:220)
ErrorHandler errorHandler:  
 com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:309)
ErrorHandler errorHandler:  
 com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:301)
ErrorHandler errorHandler:  
 com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:442)
ErrorHandler errorHandler:  
 com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
ErrorHandler errorHandler:  
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Please Help me.

Comment: seems fine to me... could you post the entire method?

Comment: Please post the full stacktrace (assuming this isn't a compile time error)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel  i have added stacktrace. Please check.

Comment: What happens in `formMsgContents()`, it looks like that is setting an invalid content type.

Comment: hey @MarkRotteveel, this is because of invalid content type. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting invalid Content type because at the time of transit white space added to respective string so log into console and try again.